# Sql find_in_set group concat not working in laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel

The query below results data like this

```
select
  products.name,
  products.image,
  products.image_second,
  products.description,
  products.min_order,
  size_categories.size_id,
  products.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    sizes.name
    order by
      FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)
  ) as sizes_name,
  units.name as units_name
from
  `products`
  inner join `subcategories` on `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id`
  inner join `size_categories` on `subcategories`.`categories_id` = `size_categories`.`categories_id`
  inner join `sizes` on FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id) > '0'
  inner join `units` on `units`.`id` = `products`.`units_id`
where
  `products`.`id` = '1'
group by
  `products`.`name`,
  `products`.`image`,
  `products`.`image_second`,
  `products`.`description`,
  `products`.`min_order`,
  `size_categories`.`size_id`,
  `products`.`id`
```

```
name | image | image_second | description | min_order | size_id | id | sizes_name | units_name

Pr1    up/..     uploads/...    sdsds          123       1,2       1    2m,3m        Piece(s)
```

The query is right,
but now i want the price too,
so i have to add a join to products_prices table, each product's sizes have different prices.
How can i get that?
I tried this query, but it gives me two rows

```
select products.name, products.image, products.image_second, 
products.description, products.min_order, size_categories.size_id, 
products.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT( product_prices.price ) as price,
GROUP_CONCAT( sizes.name order by FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id) ) as sizes_name, 
units.name as units_name 
from `products` 
inner join `subcategories` on `products`.`subcategories_id` = `subcategories`.`id` 
inner join `size_categories` on `subcategories`.`categories_id` = `size_categories`.`categories_id` 
inner join `sizes` on FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id) > '0' 
inner join `units` on `units`.`id` = `products`.`units_id` 
inner join product_prices on product_prices.products_id = products.id 
where `products`.`id` = '1' 
group by `products`.`name`, `products`.`image`, 
`products`.`image_second`, 
`products`.`description`, `products`.`min_order`, 
`size_categories`.`size_id`, `products`.`id`,product_prices.price
```

The result is like this

```
------ size_id | id | price | sizes_name
------  1,2       1   32,32     2m,3m   
------  1,2       1   43,43     2m,3m
```

32 is the price of 2m, and 43 is the price of 3m.
I need it in a single row and also i need to maintain the order (it should be like 32,43 and not like 43,32)
Please Help

Comment: If I understand correctly then use `GROUP_CONCAT(price ORER BY FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id))`, and remove excess column from GROUP BY expression.

Comment: i removed the `group by product_prices.price`  and added  `GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id))` , its showing price like `43,32,43,32` and sizes_name as `2m,2m,3m,3m` in one row

Comment: Each posessional pair (price, size) is unique, everything seems to be logically correct.

Comment: it should show `32,43` and `2m,3m` in the same order.

Comment: You must provide a fiddle with some simplified adequate model (or at least CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) and show desired output for shown data. Now it is unclear.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=67da883152e4ffb6df2cc25b96d5d5c6

Comment: You have set only partial relation for `product_prices`. It does not take into account the  relation between price and size. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ec6770b01b703728bf5d7934d8cc686e)

Comment: Yeah thank you, i missed that part

Comment: PS. I think DISTINCT in GROUP_CONCAT is now excess...

Comment: yes i removed it, thank you